# Multi-Line Log File Parsing with Ruby Regex in FluentD

Tags: regex, ruby, fluentd

I've got a log that has lines like this:

```
6/10/2022 10:06:16.908 | INFO | CLASS | BlankStart,15,1,2
```

But sometimes, the log msg is a long json blob over multiple lines.

Example bag log line:

```
6/10/2022 10:06:16.908 | INFO | CLASS | Obj: { "test": false,
"reso": true }
```

Full example w/ 3 matches:

```
6/10/2022 10:06:16.908 | INFO | CLASS | BlankStart,15,1,2
6/10/2022 10:06:16.908 | INFO | CLASS | Obj: { "test": false,
"reso": true }
6/10/2022 10:06:16.908 | INFO | CLASS | BlankStart,15,1,2
```

Here is my Regex as it stands, which I added 'strict' date checking for new lines to, for now, just get the end of the msg and ignore the multi lines.

```
(?<time>^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+)...(?<type>.[^| ]*)...(?<class>.[^| ]*)..(?<msg>.*)
```

In the fluent docs they talk about using `\m`, but I can't understand how to use this in the Regex correctly.

https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp#multiline

[image]

Comment: That should be `/m` at the end of your regex i.e. `/regex/m`.

Comment: @Azeem you know, I was trying to do `/flag` and I kept getting errors on `rubular` but I just saw they have hardcoded in the final `/` and another box for `flag` on the right. I'll try, I'm guessing my `regex` line will need adjustment too beyond the `multi-line` flag tho.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to look at [multiline](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline) parser plugin instead of fiddling with that flag directly.

Comment: @Azeem that multiline plugin looks like what I want! Thank you!

Comment: @Azeem did you want to write-up answer? That did work, tiny bit of adjustment, but it was perfect!!! Thank You

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it to work. You're welcome! You self-answered it. That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from `regex` to [`multiline`](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline) in the `parse` section made things much better. I was able to define the "start of a log format" and it understood to continue the last log for each line until a match was received for a new "start of a log".

```xml
<parse>
  @type multiline
  format_firstline /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+/  
  format1 /^(?<time>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+)...(?<type>.[^| ]*)...(?<class>.[^| ]*)..(?<msg>.*)/
</parse>
```